# IDLE (Python GUI) is displaying georgian language characters as questioning marks

Tags: python, character-encoding

When I type Georgian characters in python interactive shell,it displays question marks instead of actual characters.I tried to use text editor for creating .py file and also added comment at the first line :
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = "მე"
print a`

when I execute script,I still get question marks printed. What can I do to make python print Georgian characters instead of question marks in shell? I am using python 2.7 on windows (32bit).

additional info: I tried the same thing with Russian characters:
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a = "вфывфыв"
print a`

but when I execute it ,it displays totally different thing:

```
Ð²Ñ„Ñ‹Ð²Ñ„Ñ‹Ð²
```

Comment: Try putting a `u` at the beginning of the string, like `a = u"вфывфыв"`

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thanks! that worked ,but I wonder why can't I type Georgian characters(they appear as question marks,Russian ones don't) directly into the interactive shell,but if I copy and paste they appear normally and unicode works as well?

Comment: that's probably some issue with your font, or keyboard setup, or something else.